# Does Solo ever return to Corellia?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, solo-a-star-wars-story

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, Han Solo speaks frequently about his desire to return to his home planet of Corellia to be with his special lady.

Of course, later

> She makes contact with him on another world and formally breaks up with him.

In current Disney canon (not Legends), does Solo ever return to Corellia for any reason after escaping it through enlistment in the Imperial forces, or does he avoid it the way Vader hated Tatooine?

Answer (score 4):

[Encountering Lady Proxima](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Han_Solo#Encountering_Lady_Proxima)

**Solo returned to Corellia for parts for the Millennium Falcon alongside
Chewbacca**.

During this, Moloch, who was a member of the White Worms, captured Solo and Chewbacca and brought them to Proxima. When Moloch brought Solo and Chewbacca into Den of the White Worms, Proxima told him he would be punished because he owed her coaxium and gave her face scars from sunlight. Chewbacca gave Solo a thermal detonator, which he used to explode the window which brought in sunlight. The sunlight damaged Praxima's face again and blinded her right eye as Solo and Chewbacca made their escape [1].

1. ["Flight of the Falcon, Part 4: Lady and the Tramp"—Star Wars Adventures 17](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Flight_of_the_Falcon,_Part_4:_Lady_and_the_Tramp)